# create array of objects (multiple keys and values)

Tags: object, extjs, multidimensional-array, key-value

I created var object then put in key and values.

I can call key and object[key] however there are some keys that are repeated such as

```
    key = A,
    key = B,
    key = A,
    key = B
```

I want to separate the first two objects in array[0][0] and array[0][1]
and the other two in array[1][0] and array[1][1]. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Deending on your needs, you can make an array of arrays as such.

```
var arr  = new Array();
arr.push([{key:"A"}, {key:"B"}]);
arr.push([{key:"A"}, {key:"B"}]);
```

console logs =>

```
arr[0][0]
Object {key: "A"}
arr[0][1]
Object {key: "B"}
arr[1][0]
Object {key: "A"}
arr[1][1]
Object {key: "B"}
```